# Cannot create my own date class

Tags: c++

I tried to create my own class which contain three variable: day, month and year. And I add two operator to compare. here is my header file and cpp file:

Header:

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class Date {
public:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    Date(int m, int d, int y); 
    bool operator< (const Date &) const; 
    bool operator== (const Date &) const; 
}

#endif
```

CPP:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "date.h"

Date::Date(int m, int d, int y)
    :day(d),month(m),year(y){}

bool Date::operator< (const Date & d2) const
{
    bool result;
    if(year<d2.year){  
        result=true;
    }
    else if (year==d2.year&&month<d2.month){
        result=true;
    }
    else if (month==d2.month&&day<d2.day){
        result = true;
    }
    else{
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

bool Date::operator== (const Date & d2) const
{
    return (year==d2.year)&&(month==d2.month)&&(day==d2.day);
}
```

The error is

> error C2533: 'Date::{ctor}' : constructors not allowed a return type

Thank you for the help!

Comment: missing semicolon at the end of class declaration.

Comment: Why do you need any of those include files in your header?  You are not using any of them in the header!

Comment: Your cpp file is not using the extra include files either.  I highly recommend getting rid of *stdafx.h*, as it causes more problems with small files than it resolves.

Comment: You should write a unit test for this class and make sure that `!(Date(MAY, 5, 2013) < Date(MAY, 5, 2012))`.

Answer (score 2):

The class definition lacks a semicolon at the end.

---

Other comments:

- To avoid name collisions (e.g. with `std::distance`), do not put a `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header.
- `<stdafx.h>` is a non-standard header, defined in your Visual Studio project, which makes that code dependent on Visual Studio. You can avoid it by turning off "precompiled headers" in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

the declaration of class or struct must end with ' ; '